# Starvation prevention and ReentrantLock(true);

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have a monitor with the following structure

```
 if( [condition lock condition])
 {

    do{

    cond.lock()


    }while([condition lock condition]);
 }
```

Will ReentrantLock(true) prevent any possible starvation cases? Putting true as an argument to the ReentrantLock() constructor creates a FIFO queue managed by the JVM; however, if we keep calling cond.lock() with the while loop isn't it possible that a certain thread starve?

Comment: I am curious under which real implementation this would be reasonable code?

Answer (score 1):

The boolean parameter to the constructor is for Fairness. In this case giving priority to the longest waiting thread. It will have no impact on the scenario you are describing.

There are no starvation issues with recursive locks by the same thread. But there is a limit of 2147483647 such calls.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock(boolean)

Comment: I can't imagine an application that reaches that limit *legitimately*.

Comment: it will have no impact? you mean it is useless in this case? but didn't you say that the jvm looks at the waiting time and not when the lock was recently called?

Comment: I didn't post the code, but in my code there are multiple threads.

Comment: But with a reentrant lock, the recursive locks won't unwind to the extend that they let another thread in.

Comment: because of lock.lock() and lock.unlock()? i thought so too, because there should be mutual exclusion, but then if threads didn't run in parallel, it would lead to a deadlock, because the condition would always remain true.

Answer (score 0):

All reentrant means is that if the code requires the lock for an object is already has, it will continue.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html